# Is there a way to attach a debugger to apt or javac?

Tags: java, apt

I am writing an annotation processor and at a place or other I would like to just attach a debugger like in every java program. The usual

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

is rejected. Any idea on alternative ways to attach a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on the following resources:
http://code.google.com/p/acris/wiki/AnnotationProcessing_DebuggingEclipse

http://code.google.com/p/acris/wiki/AnnotationProcessing_DebuggingMaven

Although I used to separate the processor to layers: one that is not processor dependent that can be tested using regular unit tests. I did debugging of whole system using log file...

Comment: Does that work because they are a wrapper around the complier call in tools.jar? The options described clearly don't directly work on `apt` or `javac` as my original option line.